# create table coulmn name with database value

Tags: php

I should be write report page with php.this report include one table that get information from database. my structure like that:

```
  technician_id     psp_id   percent  pm_date

 -------------     ------- --------  --------

       8             16        50    13940415
       10            16        40    13940416
       12            16        60    13940417
```

I want show table like :

```
   technician_name  13940415   13940416   13940417 

   --------------   --------   --------   ---------

         ali           16         00         00
        abbas          00         40         00
        ahmad          00         00         60
```

I need help soon.thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, I'd recommend you take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and perhaps googled for some tutorials on php and database interaction, SO isn't a free coding place, show some effort :)

Comment: Post more code please. Without code we can't work.

Answer (score 0):

my code:

```
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td></td>";
$date_value = mysql_query("select  pmcontrol.* from pmcontrol")or  die(mysql_error());
$count=mysql_num_rows($date_value);

                        while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($date_value)){
                         $arr = array();
                        echo"<td>".$rows['pmdate']."</td>";
                        for($k=0;$k<31 ;$k++){

                        $arr[$k]=$rows['pmdate'];
                          }
                         }
                         echo"</tr>";   
                         $search=mysql_query("select pmcontrol.*,user.*  

                         from        pmcontrol
                         INNER JOIN  user
                         on          user.u_id=pmcontrol.technician_id
                         INNER JOIN  psp
                         on          psp.id=pmcontrol.psp_id
                         where       pmcontrol.pmdate between $from_date and $until_date
                         group by    technician_id

                      ") or die(mysql_error());
   $count=mysql_num_rows($search);

   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($search)){
   echo"<tr>"; 
   echo"<td>".$row['user_name']."  ".$row['user_family']."</td>";
   for($k=0;$k<2;$k++){
   if($row['pmdate']=$arr[$k]){
   echo"<td>".$row['percent']."</td>";
   }
   else if($row['pmdate']!=$arr[$k]) {

   echo"<td>00</td>";   
   }}
   echo"</tr>";
    }

   echo "</table>";
```

my result :

```
  technician_name     13940415  13940416  13940417
  ---------------     --------  --------  --------

         ali             16        16        16
         abbas           40        40        40
         ahmad           60        60        60
```